# Requisição retornando Cannot PUT com express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Saudações dev's o meu arquivo de rotas está assim:

```
const express = require('express')
const routes = express.Router()

const TodoController = require('./controllers/TodoController')

...

routes.put('/todo/:id', TodoController.alterTodo)

module.exports = routes
```

Dentre outros métodos que estão funcionando o meu controller está assim:

```
const TodoModel = require('../models/TodoModel')

module.exports = {
   ...
    async alterTodo(req, res) {
    try {
        await TodoModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
            item: req.body.item,
            done: req.body.done
        })

        res.json({
            message: 'Seu TODO foi atualizado com sucesso.',
            ...req.body
        })
    } catch (e) {
        res.json({
            message: e
        })
    }
}}
```

Estou passando a minha URL desta forma:

> http://localhost:3000/todos/5c7b50cb4a73110d68704251

Enquanto o ID do item que eu quero atualizar não tem nada errado, pois as minhas requisições GET estão retornando esse mesmo id que passo no URL, além de eu estar sempre copiando e colando para não ter erros desse tipo.

Porém ao tenta fazer essa requisição ela não entra nem no meu catch e me retorna um status 404 com uma string pura dizendo "Cannot PUT /todos/5c7b50cb4a73110d68704251".

OBS: Não estou deixando de passar o json com o dados a ser atualizado e estou usando a versão mais recente do mongoose(5.4.16) e express(4.16.4)

Comment: Ué, na sua chamada você faz `/todos` e na definição está `routes.put('/todo/:id', TodoController.alterTodo)`

Comment: Meu Deus mano, não acredito que era isso kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk. Obrigado isso resolveu mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está fazendo a chamada `http://localhost:3000/todos/5c7b50cb4a73110d68704251` no plural porém definiu a rota no singular. Altere a criação da rota para:

```
routes.put('/todos/:id', TodoController.alterTodo);
```